# Azure AD: UWP App automatically logging into Azure AD (certificate or known credentials)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm doing a POC of a an application for use on a touch screen device running windows 10.
The currently UWP (although open to nearly any app that can run full screen for a kiosk) app already has a webview control and I can control the url where I want to navigate to. In some situations, I'd like to navigate to a 3rd party webapp that is using Azure AD authentication.

Interactively, we can login but I'd like to have the login happen automatically using a known azure ad username and password or ideally a certificate we can install on the device. We don't own the web app (so we can't change any properties on it) but its connected to our Azure AD tenant so we own the azure ad app configuration. The web application does not have API's yet to consume the information. The device uses local accounts, per the guidance on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-prepare.

I've used the (Public/Confidential)ClientApplicationBuilder which works for getting tokens to talk to web apis but I'd like to do a form post to something (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}) ? and then redirect to the web app when done. I've looked into OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) and it seems the closest but I'm not sure how to take the access token I receive and somehow save it (in a cookie?) so the web app will log the user in when navigated to. I'm sure I could watch the various URLS and fill in the credentials programatically but that seems wrong. I've reviewed the various Azure AD samples but I've not seen one that fits my scenario (which might indicate a flaw in the plan...).